# Using a vector as a reference for dataframes, how can I apply functions to all dataframes within vector?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have 18 uniform dataframes and would like to change the column names of each of these dataframes to the same column names.  Here is a working example for just 2 but I would like this to scale.

```r
df1 <- data.frame("value1" = 1:10, "value2" = 1)
df2 <- data.frame("value1" = 1:10, "value2" = 2)
column.names <- c("new1", "new2")
df.list <- as.list(df1, df2)
```

So far I have tried both **lapply** and a **for** loop

```r
df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {
  colnames(x) <- column.names
  x
})
```

```r
for (i in seq_along(df.list)) {
  colnames(df.list[[i]]) <- column.names
}
```

but neither work and both produce the following error

```r
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = column.names) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need `as.list` as the `as.list` converts each unit element to a `list` and it only takes a single argument.  According to `?as.list`

> as.list(x, ...)
>
> x - object to be coerced or tested.

So, what it will do is to create a `list` from the columns of 'df1' and not take 'df2' i.e.

```
as.list(df1, df2)
#$value1
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#$value2
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Note that these are just the columns of 'df1'.  To place both the objects in `list`, use the `list`

```
df.list <-  list(df1, df2)
```

Comment: Great! That fixed it up perfect.  Can't believe it was something that simple.  Now the problem I am running into is that these dataframes with the changed names are now  stored inside the list.  Is there an easy way to store them in the environment, outside of the list?